# vscode Golang debugging launch.json configuration

Tags: go, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Trying to use vscode debugger to debug my go code.
vscode runs all the .go files in the same dir using the following launch.json config file:

```json
        {
            "name": "Test",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "test",
            "program": "${relativeFileDirname}",
        }
```

Obviously, I tried to change
`"program": "${relativeFileDirname}",` -> `"program": "${file}",` but it's not working.
In addition, is there a way I can run ut and not the whole file (or in this case the whole dir)?

Comment: If you are trying to run the debugger for your code and not the tests, the `mode` parameter should be set to `debug` and not `test`. You can take a look at this extensive documentation for setup steps, supported features, configurations, information on remote debugging and a troubleshooting guide: https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/wiki/debugging

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following launch.json configuration to run the main.go file in the same directory as .vscode. Change the file name main.go to the corresponding go file to run them

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "some name",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "main.go",
        }
    ]
}
```